# jquery scrollTo + wordpress issue (horizontal sliding layout)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scrollto, horizontal-scrolling

Basically I tried to make a horizontal sliding one-page layout.
I struggled for hours and still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

JQuery and scrollTo are included before `<?php wp_head(); ?>` (in right order) and I checked twice for possible typos.

Gere's my html markup:

```
<div class="nav">
<a class="menu" href="#main">main</a>
<a class="menu" href="#bio">bio</a>
<a class="menu" href="#film">film</a><br>
</div>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="mask">
    <div class="panel" id="main"> </div>
    <div class="panel" id="bio"> </div>
    <div class="panel" id="film"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here's the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.menu').click(function () {

    $('a.menu').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    current = $(this);

    $('#wrap').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);     

    return false;
});

});

</script>
```

I tried to place this script everywhere on the site, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of 404 errors for the JS files when I go to your site.  Are you sure you're loading the libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the basic idea down but I think the problem lies in how you have your scrollable panel and its container set up.

Using your above code as an example, I have implemented a basic ScrollTo sliding layout:

- **Vertical Scroll** - http://jsfiddle.net/ZqSSm/1/ - Note how the height of `#mask` would be `2400px` (800px * 3), but only the first `500px` are visible.
- **Horizontal Scroll** - http://jsfiddle.net/ZqSSm/2/ - Note how the width of `#horizontalwrap` is `2400px`, but only the first `500px` are visible.

If you need any more help, drop me a line and I'll do my best! ScrollTo was a headache for me when first using it!

*Note that there are also some problems loading the JS files on your website. I don't know the cause but opening chrome's developer console or firebug will let you see what's going on.*

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i think the problem doesn't lie in html structure. it worked perfectly before i implemented it to wordpress.

i changed links to scripts to absolute paths, but still nothing happens.

the console throws 'Uncaught exception: TypeError: '$.scrollTo' is not a function'. this may be a hint!

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right. I'm not exactly sure what the root of the problem is, but just double check how you're including your javascript files. I can see at the minute you are loading JQuery twice, which might be causing things to fail.

`<script src="http://estrma.net/DYBLIK/dyblik/wp-content/themes/html5blank/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>`

&

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! i deregistered jquery loaded by deafult in functions.php an it worked!